# Facebook canvas horizontal scroll bar issue

Tags: facebook-canvas

My facebook apps 
page canvas width 760px.
iFrame page body width 520px, overflow:hidden.

Still showing horizontal scroll only in firefox 9, 10. IE and Chrome looks fine.

[image]

Is there any solution of this issue?

Comment: Only in those browsers it doesn't work... How about safari? opera? konqueror? Lynx? ;)

Comment: Safari work fine. We need to care for Firefox not opera, konqueror or Lynx.

Answer (score 0):

You should review your canvas settings for your application through the [developers application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

[image]

As  you can see there are two settings for the canvas width. When you use the **fluid** setting for the width, there is no "limit" to the width - your application can take up as much space as the users screen can give.  This of course excludes the reserved space for the sidebar with the ticker and the advertisements.
The **fixed** setting is self explanatory.
Another option would be to use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and the [FB.Canvas.setSize()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) method.  The syntax is very straight forward :
`FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });`
Happy coding!

Comment: Height already set fluid but still doesn't work. We have tried both FB.Canvas.setAutoResize() and FB.Canvas.setSize() function.